# How to solve the avoid mutating a prop

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to compare prices from last year and this year and the problem I'm getting is this:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value

I understand what it's saying but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label for="year_select">Select Year</label>
                                    <select id="year_select" @change="getYearComparison()" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" v-model="yearSelect">
                                        <option v-for="year in years" :value="year.id">
                                            {{ year.year }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <table class="table">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr class="text-center">
                                                                <th colspan="4" style="border-right: #dee2e6 solid 1px">
                                                                    Previous Year
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th colspan="3" style="border-right: #dee2e6 solid 1px">
                                                                    This year
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th colspan="2">
                                                                    Variance
                                                                </th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>

                                                        <tr v-for="c in compare">
                                                            <td>
                                                                {{ c.prev_price }}
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td>
                                                                {{ c.curr_price }}
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td style="border-right: #dee2e6 solid 1px">
                                                                {{ c.v_price }}
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['compare'],
        data(){
            return {
               years: [],
               tariffSelect: null
            }
        },
        computed: {

        },
        methods: {
            getYears(){
                axios.get('/api/years/getYears').then(response => {
                    this.years = response.data.years;
                });
            },
            getYearComparison(){
                axios.get(`/api/product/${this.tariffSelect}/comparison`).then(response => {
                    this.compare = response.data.compare;
                })
            }

        },
        mounted(){
            this.getYears();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try this, Remove `props: ['compare']` and add `compare` into the `data` property.

Answer (score 0):

`compare` is a prop, meaning that it's to be transferred to your component, the "child" by another component (or the Vue app), the "parent". On the other end, your child component should communicate a value change to its parent using an event.

In your parent component, you can do this:

```html
<template>
  <child-component :compare="compare" @updateCompare="compare = $event"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default { 
    data() { 
      return { compare: '' }; // Put a default value here that makes sense
    }
  };
</script>
```

And in your child component, you need to emit the event, so you can replace this line:

```js
this.compare = response.data.compare;
```

By this one:

```js
this.$emit('updateCompare', response.data.compare);
```

You can take a look at [the documentation for events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).